# how can i create a installer package in flex air?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I need to create a installer package which application i developed using flex air. Now how can i create a installer package of this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main menu -> Project -> Export release build
It will make you an .air installation file of your app.